# Codename One: Webservice not available

Tags: web-services, servlets, codenameone

I used the CN1 Webservice Wizard to add a the webservice proxy to my mobile app and to generate all the server side code. I have a local XAMPP installation with a tomcat linked within my Eclipse IDE. Also, I imported the server generated code as a new Java Project and added the "Dynamic Web Module" project facet to it so that I could launch it not as a local Java application but rather on the Tomcat server.

When starting my client, I noted that I get `HTTP 404`, resource not found errors. I traced the error back to the URL, where the server is hosted to.
I know I have to adapt the `urlPatterns` parameter in the generated class `CN1WebServiceServlet`, which I did. Also, I checked the context of my app in the Web project settings and defined the value for `context root`. So, in my client app, the URL to call the service should be

`http://localhost:8080/< context root>/< urlPattern>`

However, even when calling that in the browser, I should get the result of the `doGet` method of the server generated code, showing the message "Webservice access only". Instead, I get 404 errors all the time.

Is there some problem to importing the server generated code as a plain Java project and adding the web parts to it afterwards? How would that be done in the ideal case? 
And what other problems might be hindering the URL from properly being published on the server side?

Thanks and best regards

EDIT

I stripped everything from the project to limit the options and I found the cause: when using the web service wizard to dump the source files into a new directory, adding that with the Eclipse import wizard, it will be looked at as a plain java project without any web components. Using the project settings to add the dynamic web piece to it (Eclipse calls those project facets), the CN1 webservice will NOT work.

If instead you create a "Dynamic Web Project" first and then use the CN1 Webservice Wizard to dump the server source files into the "src" folder of that project, it works without any issues.

Comment: If this doesn't work from the browser it means the servlet/tomcat configuration isn't picking up. The context shouldn't be in the servlet. It's a part of the web app. It should match the context of your web app. I'm not sure if the external jar would be picked I suggest adding the code into your server project to get started

Comment: see my edit above. What is the difference between the webservice wizard creating the files as plain text files or adding them to an existing web project? I ran a file watcher during the wizard and I have not found any other changes than dumping the source files in both scenarios. So there should not be any difference whether one adds the web facet or uses a web project to begin with.

Comment: I don't understand what you did. Notice that a web project will use the annotations within the file in runtime, if you just created a regular java project it won't use that.